# Get The AVPlayer instance from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, background, avfoundation, avplayer

Im trying to Playing Audio from a Video Asset in the Background
As Apple mentioned in the following example [Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/playing_audio_from_a_video_asset_in_the_background?language=objc)

We need to set the AVPlayer to nil so that the app continue playing the audio in the background .

[image]

the problem is how to get the  AVPlayer instance from AppDelegate
I tried this method but nothing work and the app crash when I Enter the Background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    Player *PlayerViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    PlayerViewController.VideoPlayer = nil;
}
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Home setVideoPlayer:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104835000'

also I tried this and its not wokring

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    Player *PlayerViewController ;
    PlayerViewController.VideoPlayer = nil;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

we need to controll applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationDidEnterBackground in the same Player UIViewController class by adding this 2

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(disconnectAVPlayer) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification  object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reconnectAVPlayer) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification  object:nil];
```

then we can set VideoPlayer to nil like this

```
- (void)disconnectAVPlayer{
    self.playerLayer.player = nil;
}

- (void)reconnectAVPlayer{
    self.playerLayer.player = self.VideoPlayer;    
}
```

NOTE : We need to set AVPlayerLayer to nil not the actual AVPlayer